# sql using offset row fetch not enough results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

when requesting results using OFFSET row fetch, what happens if there are less than the m number of results found? How would you handle it efficiently?

```
SELECT column-names
FROM table-name
ORDER BY column-names
OFFSET n ROWS
FETCH NEXT m ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: `OFFSET n ROWS` and `FETCH NEXT m ROW ONLY` is not [supported syntax in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). MySQL supports `LIMIT [n,] m` or `LIMIT m OFFSET n`. If less than `m` rows are found, MySQL simply returns the remaining rows (or zero, if none remaining). But why don't you just try it out and see what happens?

Comment: I'll try it, I need to get my logic in order

Answer (score 0):

It's always possible for a result set to contain fewer rows than expected. A wise programmer never assumes a result set will have a precise predicted number of rows, but always uses a loop based on whether any rows remain. You keep reading rows until you've read them all.

Some perfectly normal result sets might contain no rows at all. Consider the case where the table contains exactly 20 rows and you read them 10 at a time. The third chunk of 10 rows will be empty.

The example in the documentation for mysqli's [`fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) method makes this clear.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        /* process the row ... */
    }
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```